# Trying to write a basic script for a Google Sheets that will count total missed minutes by late students

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am (VERY) new to Apps Script and JS generally. I am trying to write a script that will automatically tally the difference between student entry time and start time of a course to deliver total minutes missed.

I have been able to get a function working that can do this for a single cell value, but am having trouble iterating it across a range. Doubtless this is due to a fundamental misunderstanding I have about the for loop I am using, but I am not sure where to look for more detailed information.

Any and all advice is appreciated. Please keep in mind my extreme "beginner status".

I have tried declaring a blank variable and adding multiple results of previously written single-cell functions to that total, but it is returning 0 regardless of given information.

I am including all three of the functions below, the idea is that each will do one part of the overall task.

````
function LATENESS (entry,start) {
return (entry-start)/60000
}

function MISSEDMINUTES(studenttime,starttime) {
  const time = studenttime;
  const begin = starttime;
  if (time=="Present") {
    return 0
  } else if (time=="Absent") {
    return 90
  } else {
    return LATENESS(time,begin)
  }
}


function TOTALMISSED(range,begintime) {
  var total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    total = total + MISSEDMINUTES(i,begintime)
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Based on the example, you could probably have a formula like the below one to conduct your summation:

`=Sum(ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:E2="Absent",90,if(isnumber(B2:E2),(B2:E2-$K$1)*60*24,0))))`

Note that `k1` has the start time of 10:00. Same [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mE6AMPxDl9BgRisPmplmzZYljmFTBpl2IAaLGFME6XA/edit#gid=0) has working example.

[image: If you had your data as your shared:]

### Original Answer

I'm pretty sure you could do what you want with regular sheets formulas. [Here'a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mE6AMPxDl9BgRisPmplmzZYljmFTBpl2IAaLGFME6XA/edit#gid=0) that shows how to get the difference in two times in minutes and seconds... Along with accounting for absent.

Here's the formula used that will update with new entries.

`=Filter({if(B2:B="Absent",90*60,Round((C2:C-B2:B)*3600*24,0)),if(B2:B="Absent",90,Round((C2:C-B2:B)*3600*24/60,1))},(B2:B<>""))`

This example might not solve all your issues, but from what I'm seeing, there's no need to be using an app script. If this doesn't cover it, post some sample data using [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had a sinking suspicion that it could be done without Script, but wasn't sure. I made a simple version of the way the data is laid out: 

| Name          | 2/6     | 2/7     | 2/8     | 2/9    | Ideal Totals                |
|---------------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------------------------|
| John Smith    | Present | Present | Absent  | 10:06  | 90+6 = 96 minutes missed    |
| Lucy Jenkins  | Absent  | Absent  | Absent  | Absent | 90 * 4 = 360 minutes missed |
| Darren Polter | Present | Present | Present | 10:01  | 1 minute missed             |

Comment: @GarnetPilfer updated with a formula that would do what you expect. Assuming that works, please don't forget to hit the accept icon, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you slightly tweak your layout to have the 'missing minutes' column immediately adjacent to the column of names, you can have a single formula which will calculate the missing minutes for any number of students over any number of days:

| Name | * | 2/6 | 2/7 | 2/8 | 2/9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | - | Present | Present | Absent | 10:06 |
| Lucy Jenkins | - | Absent | Absent | Absent | Absent |
| Darren Polter | - | Present | Present | Present | 10:01 |

With 'Name' present in A1, add the following to cell B1 (where I've marked an asterisk):

```
={"mins missed";
byrow(map(
C2:index(C2:ZZZ,counta(A2:A),counta(C1:1)),
          lambda(x,switch(x,"Present",0,"Absent",90,,0,1440*(x-timevalue("10:00"))))),
      lambda(row,sum(row)))}
```

We are MAPping a minute value onto each entry in the table (where 'Present'=0, 'Absent'=90 & a time entry = the number of minutes difference between then and 10am), then summing BYROW.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the ARRAYFORMULA function from Google Sheets, but I am going to try out this solution on my own to learn some new stuff. Thanks for the help!